# Find parent of searched item using ZSH

Tags: zsh, wildcards

My sub-directory has multiple .git repo. To Find them I am using:

```
$ echo **/.git        
demo-component-a/.git demo-component-b/.git
```

Now I actually need the parent directories. `demo-component-a` & `demo-component-b`.

I found this neat feature to find the parent of a path:

```
$ var=/home/blueray/Documents/antora/demo-component-b
$ echo $var:h
/home/blueray/Documents/antora
```

Now I am trying to combine these two.

I have tried the following:

```
$ echo $(echo **/.git):h 
demo-component-a/.git demo-component-b/.git:h
```

This is not what I want. What can be done here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
**/.git(:h)
```

The `h` [history modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) strips the filename component off of each pathname. To use a history modifier on the result of a wildcard expansion, put it in a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers): in parentheses at the end, with a leading `:` to indicate that it's a history modifier.

To only find directories, which would exclude git linked working trees, use `(/:h)` as the glob qualifier.

As you found out, that `:h` history modifier can also be applied on parameter expansions (like in `csh` where that feature comes from). In `zsh`, you can also apply it to each word resulting of the `$IFS` splitting of a command substitution, by writing it:

```
print -rC1 -- ${$(echo **/.git):h}
```

The above would be wrong for other reasons though (like usage of `echo`, splitting file paths on SPC+TAB+NL+NULL). To be equivalent to `**/*.git(:h)`, that would rather be:

```
print -rC1 -- ${(0)"$(print -rNC1 -- **/*.git)"}
```

Comment: It takes 10 min to accept an answer. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @blueray Well, it's good to give others a chance to come up with a better solution... :-)

Comment: By the way, if I need to run `git commit -am "Latest Commit"` in all these directories, how can I do that?

Comment: @blueray `for dir in **/.git(/:h); do git -C $dir commit ...; done` But you don't need the `:h` for that I think.

Comment: Why would you use `(/:h)` here? It would exclude git worktrees, where `.git` is a regular file rather than a directory, and I don't see any reason to exclude worktress here.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I'm slightly confused by your edit. What does "history modifier" have to do with this? The `:h` modifier is used as a  filename generation modifier in this context.

Comment: @Kusalananda More precisely, `h` is a history modifier. `:X` in a glob qualifier says to apply the history modifier `X` to the result.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I see what you mean now. Ok, thanks.

Comment: @blueray, or `for d (**/.git) git -C $d:h commit`